# InDesign: display delta x/y values (instead of document coordinates) when moving an object

Tags: adobe-indesign

I know that Illustrator and Photoshop both do a great job of showing you how far you have moved an object, in relation to its original position.  As it is, InDesign displays the object's coordinates and that is all.  Is there a way to display the delta values?  I'm sick of doing this mentally, especially because ID can often go to 4 decimal spaces.

Photoshop:

[image: Photoshop]

Illustrator:

[image: Illustrator]

InDesign:

[image: InDesign]

You can see how much easier it is to determine how far you have moved an object in the first two programs, versus InDesign.  How do I get InDesign to play nice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it's not a built-in option. (But I agree that it's yet another example of these "Suite" programs behaving infinitesimally different. Perhaps it *should* be an option -- and then the same for all three programs!)

Did you know you can drag the ruler zero point to any place? If you drag it to the starting point of from where you want to drag, you can see "live" over what distance you drag the object. A simple double-click on the horizontal and vertical intersection of the rules resets the zero point to its proper position.

Instead of dragging (which is touchy at best), you can also use the "Position" indicators in the Control Bar. To move something by an exact delta, just type it in with a plus or minus after the current value; for example, if an x position is shown as "25.34 mm", adding "+ 5" at the end will move your object horizontally by exactly 5 mm.

Comment: Seems like an effective workaround, until Adobe get their act together, Thanks!  It's only been 15 years, since ID came out...

Comment: I agree, it is also funny how PS and AI offer the same feature, but yet both go about it in different ways.  Maybe they figure that PS users aren't smart enough to understand what the variable delta stands for?  I'll never quite understand why Adobe do what they do.